# UIGestureRecognizer swipe and hold

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement the effect of scrolling through a menu. If the user does a single swipe (in any direction) I will move one item for each swipe. This is working just fine using `UISwipeGestureReconizer`, but if the user  keeps holding there finger down on the screen after the swipe I want to keep scrolling until the finger has lifted.

It seems like I would want to combine `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to accomplish this. After a successful swipe (`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`), enable the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and start scrolling until a finger has lifted (`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` ends).

The problem is that `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` event does not occur after a successful swipe.

Heres an example:

```
// Create single swipe recognizer to recognize right swipes
swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleSwipeFrom:)];
swipeRecognizer.delegate = self;
[_gestureView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];

// Create long press recognizer to recognize right press and holds
longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeAndHoldFrom:)];
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
[longPressRecognizer setMinimumPressDuration:0.5];
[longPressRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
[_gestureView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
[longPressRecognizer release];

- (void)handleSingleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // Move one item in direction based on recognizer.direction
        [_longPressGestureRecognizer setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

If I keep my finger on the screen after the swipe, the UILongPressGestureRecognizer event is never called. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468648/how-do-i-chain-two-uigesturerecognizers-together

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I get the same behaviour as you.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and use this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

This will allow the two to run simultaneously. You will need to add code into the **handle swipe and hold** method though in order to make sure it is only being run after the swipe is completed.

Cheers

Comment: I do that already. I have both the UISwipeGestureRecognizer and UILongPressGestureRecognizer setup for this (delegate = self) and its being called successfully for each recognizer and returning YES. I also do not enable the long press until after the swipe has ended ( it also has a delay)